# Kinesis Firehose - S3 backup -Not working - Data is NOT moving to s3 back up folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Doing kinesis Firehose "delivery stream" data into Lambda for transformation and move the data into two different location

1. Transformation / filter - s3 location
2. s3 back up.

-s3 location - i am reeving filter data. But i couldn't get entire data stream data in s3 backup folder.\

Lambda filtering condition:

```
                String status = "Dropped";
                if (data.toLowerCase().contains("apple"))
                    status = "Ok";                  
                outRec.setResult(status);
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information .

Comment: @ Amit Baranes added more information. issue with s3 backup folder "databakup" could NOT see all the data. filtering data were stored into s3 destination s3 folder. let us know if you need any further information on this

Comment: Any one came across this scenario. If yes can you please share

Answer (score 0):

what is the buffer condition you are providing?